# Collapsing remaining categorised columns in a filtered view

Tags: xpages

I have a view with 4 categorised columns and the first category is the person's name.

I have created a viewPanel and I would like to filter the view so that it only shows the current user's records. The category filter works as expected but all the categorised columns display as expanded. So I added expandLevel="1" and all the documents disappear.

Is there a way to collapse all categorised columns in a filtered view?

I have since tried setting expandLevel to "1", "2", "3" and "4". The documents disappear until it is set to "4" and the it just displays the 3 categorised columns in expanded mode anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, with a typical scenario this should work!
 Category filtering and the property 'expandLevel' set to 1 should work for you. You should see all the categorized columns collapsed for that categoryFilter and the parent documents associated with that last subcategory. 
If your data contains response documents, these will not display. Though setting 'indentResponses=true' on the column in the viewPanel will get them to display for you.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the information, it helped me to go through the view and view panel settings with a fine-tooth comb. It's now working and the reason it was displaying an empty view because I had the 'Don't show empty categories' view option selected.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in the viewpanel. You can :

1. Create your own viewpanel using repeat controls
2. Use a grid container like [this one](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8UTGAL) or [this](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8A59VP) one